# Strange Behavior of MySQL MAX function

Tags: mysql

Suppose In my MySQL table there are no row inserted yet.

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
SerialNo INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
UserID INT(9) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (SerialNo)
);
```

When I run the following MySQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO Users(UserID) SELECT MAX(UserID)+1 FROM Users;
```

The table looks like the following picture:

Image Link: https://s1.postimg.org/4r2xcc7ajj/z_Ii_A-_KUp_Tzio_-00_PBL0_KQ.png

Can anyone tell me why `MAX(UserID)+1` setting **0** instead of **1**?

Comment: Because there is no `MAX(UserID)` when the table is empty.

Comment: Then How it set 0 based on what? and How I set 1 on such case?

Comment: While this doesn't directly answer the question, why are you trying to insert the next without having it be an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field?

Comment: @KeithChason I din't use AUTO_INCREMENT because some times I need to create duplicate user id in multiple row.

Comment: max(userID) when no records exist will be null. Thus Null+1 is null but not null in create table makes the null default to 0.

Answer (score 3):

- 0 is the default value used for an int field without a default
  specified.
- Inserting null values into not null fields usually results
  in the field given the null value being assigned it's default value
  instead.
- Most aggregate functions only return null only if the
  encounter no non-null values.
- Since the table is empty, MAX returns null, and NULL + 1 is NULL.
- You're inserting null into an integer field without a default value specified.

Edit: To insert 1 in such cases use `IFNULL(MAX(UserId),0)+1`

Answer (score 0):

As mysql manual on [max()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) says: `max()` returns null if there is no matching record. If there is no record at all in the table, then `max(userid)` returns null.

`null + 1` will also be null. So, you query tries to insert null into your table.

Your mysql is configured with [strict mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict) turned off, therefore when you try to insert a null value into a non-null field, mysql silently converts the null to the fields implicit default value. This happens to be 0 for an integer field.

If strict mode were turned on, then you would get an error message for trying to insert an illegal value into your table. This way, you only get a warning.

Btw, you should turn strict mode on.

Comment: How I  assign 1 in first UserID without using 
`AUTO_INCREMENT` 
and 
`INSERT INTO USERS(UserID) VALUES(1)` ?